# Permenantly storing a string, by a user?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, settext

On my main activity I'm looking into a variable, if the variable contains a string ("example string") then it will go to the home-screen. if the variable contains nothing ("") it will redirect them to a page where they can enter a value via an `editText` and then permanently store it. So the next time they open the app, it will have this permanent string (until the app is deleted) and therefore it will just go to the home-screen.
From research i understand that i may have to use Shared Preferences. I have tried this already and I think im not doing something right. 
Please could someone illustrate with a code example of what needs to be done for the code i have posted.

**MainActivity.class**

```
//this class uses the string, to see if its blank or contains a string

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public static final String Verified = ""; //Originally comes blank

         private EditText NumberET; //editText for user to enter a string


//the string verified is used in the main activity to determine which xml file to open.
```

**Verified.class**

```
// this is the class used to enter the string and permanently store it


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verified);

Button VerifyCompleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.VerifyCompleteButton);

VerifyCompleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{
   public void onClick(View view) 
   {    

     String Verified;
         String Number;


     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

     Verified = bundle.getString("Verified");
     NumberString = bundle.getString("NumberString")

    Verified = NumberString.toString(); //set String Verified permenantly



   } 



   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Great example of using SharedPreference can be found on [Google's Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Saving data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("KEY", "VALUE");
editor.commit();
```

Get data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedValue = context.getString("KEY", "");
```

Things to look after:

- Make sure your [key] is the same for saving and getting. The shared preferences is a basically a hashmap/dictionary.
- When getting use the second parameter to set a default return value when setting isn't found or set yet.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the KEY is? and also the getActivity() ?

Comment: i get an error on both getActivity() and getString (due to getResource)

Comment: I copied the code from a Fragment, in that case getActivity is needed.  I edited my answer to use a context. Context is needed to get the prefrences and the resources/string. So depending on where you run this code you need a context or don't need one. The KEY is a unique string that you must use to get and set your preference. You can use "user_verified" for example. Typically these keys are stored in the string.xml or in a class as static final String.

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this , Very much similar to above answer 
For Saving String

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("App_Name_Prefs",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("Verified",  Verified);
editor.commit();
```

For getting string

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("App_Name_Prefs",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String keyReturn = shared.getString(key, "");
Log.d("return value" , "Verified is " + verified);
```